# Spring JPA multiply nested tables with complicated relationship M:N and 1:N

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a simple API which provides some data to the frontend.

I am struggling with database and association to the entities in Spring. Let's go step by step so you understand clearly what I need.

My example is very similar to this course: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many. Look at the `3.1` section.

1) Let's say, we have a `student` table and `course` table. Between these, there is a join table (let's call it for example `studentCourseJoin`). Ok, this seems to be nearly same as presented on Baeldung site. But in my case I need to have additional table `ratings` which is separated from join table. 
And assume that **Student can rate course multiple times** (let's say once a year)

2) My goal is to have data structure like this:

```
{
  students: [
    {
      studentID: 1,
      courses: [
        {
          courseID: 1,
          ratings: [{
            ratingID: 1,
            studentID: 1
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, if I have a student with ID 1, I want to list all his courses and all his ratings he made to the given course (as presented in the example).

I am having problem with ratings. Because I always get all ratings to the given course no matter who made the rating. Basically I am missing just one `WHERE` clause.

Example result:

```
{
  students: [
    {
      studentID: 1,
      courses: [
        {
          courseID: 1,
          ratings: [{
            ratingID: 1,
            studentID: 1
          },{
            ratingID: 2,
            studentID: 5
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Making a custom query isn't hard.. It's just about 3 `JOIN`s. But that is not what I want. I want to set up all entities right, so Hibernate can automatically make queries, delete orphans etc...

3) Input data: `studentID: 1` (and another scenario: `studentID: 1, yearRated: 2020`)

4) My question? How can I integrate `ratings` table so it applies filter `WHERE studentId == 1`. In seconds scenario `WHERE studentId == 1 AND yearRated == 2020`

What schema would I choose between these 2 ? Or do you propose different?

**Schema 1**

[image]

**Schema 2**

[image]

I am missing FK definition in `rating` table in Schema 2 (just ignore it)

I am a beginner with Spring JPA so I am missing some experience and this could be an easy question. Locally my database has quite different names and much more columns and absolutely different purpose. But I wanted to make this example as easy as possible.

For now, let's assume I have entity for each table (except join table) and I have correctly configured M:N relationship with @ManyToMany and @Jointable decorators

### Edit

Let's say, that I would like to use Schema 2. Question is, am I able to create a method name which will automatically create query with required result? (Paragraph 3). If so, what are the requirements? Do I have to create entity for join table and also embeddable entity for composite key ? and how exactly do I join `rating` table with this join table?

### EDIT 2

I created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614479/spring-jpa-multiply-nested-tables) which is simplified and should be more understandable.

Comment: When you want an answer for the question which schema is the best than you had to ask for yourself the questions: 1. Can a student give a rating for a course he doesn't follow. (schema 2 allows that) 2. Can a student give a rating for a course he doesn't follow in a certain year. (schema 1 and schema 2 allows that)

Comment: that doesn't matter in my case. The most important for me is how to apply this in Spring in each entity. Where to put many to one (or specifically, how to define it) because i dont know how to link ratings with students.will be some composite key required? simply said, is it possible to achiev this just by right definition of method name?

Comment: It does matter for a different schema will give different entities. And different entities needs different queries. When you want to select on studentId and yearRated schema 1 needs joins in the select and schema 2 doesn't.

Comment: I made an edit. Is this understandable? My english is limiting me a little bit

Comment: You can not get the desired result, because a student must not visit the course to rate the course. You expect the ratings **under** the courses, but there are independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose **Schema 2**
Than you can not get the desired result, because a student must not visit the course to rate the course. You expect the ratings under the courses, but there are independent.

Comment: Good catch. But in my case, this doesn't matter. In my code there is this one special condition that user does not need to attend the course to rate it. I chose a really bad example. Look at the new question I made :)