# Spring JPA - Multiply nested tables applying WHERE clause

Tags: database, spring, spring-data-jpa

I already created [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59565110/spring-jpa-multiply-nested-tables-with-complicated-relationship-mn-and-1n) before which was complicated. So I am creating a new one which will be as simple as possible.

I am having a problem with Spring JPA especially twice nested structure.

Here is a super simple relationship diagram:

[image]

The country has multiple rivers and rivers can flow through multiple countries. The river has multiple bridges but the bridge can be built over 1 river only. So M:N -> 1:N

This is the expected result:

```
{
  countries: [
    {
      countryID: 1,
      rivers: [
        {
          riverID: 1,
          bridges: [{
            bridgeID: 1
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is what I have.

**Country entity**

```
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ... more columns

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "country_river",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "countryid") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "riverid") })
    private Set<River> rivers = new HashSet<>();
```

**River entity**

```
public class River {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ... more columns


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "riverid")
    private Set<Bridge> Bridges;
```

Don't need to mention Bridge entity since there is only ID column specified ( I am using unidirectional relation)

The problem is, that bridges are not filtered based on country. As you can see in the expected output, I would like to list all countries and it's associated rivers and bridges on them in the given country.

Do I have to create a custom query on Bridges inside River entity (If so, how.)?  Or do I have to somehow change the structure of the database?

Comment: Is there a country with a River that has not a bridge? If always has a bridge then I think so that bridge is the  many-to-many associated entity. Or country has many bridge same river?

Comment: Of course a bridge is a building in a country, but in your model we do not know in which country the bridge is.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich it is possible that river has no bridge. And on 1 river there could be more than just 1 bridge
@TobiasOtto as you can see, I am using join table between Country and River. So it should be possible to map bridge through this table. Isn't it? If I have a `countryid` and `riverid` columns in the River table

Comment: No. It is even more complicated, when the river is the natural border between two contries connected by the bridge. So maybe you just expect another answer than it is. You have to change your model first.

Comment: @TobiasOtto please, do not think about edge cases. This is just an example. There is not a chance that Bridge will cross 2 countries. And also, you can check the previous question where I had a better explained diagram

Comment: You wrote: "I would like to list all countries and it's associated rivers and bridges on them in the given country." The problem with that are the last words: "...in the give country". 
But your model gives you every bridge over every river in this country, because we do not know in which country the bridges are. Maybe you try another example?

Comment: You can have avoid `@ManyToMany` by replacing it with `@OneToMany`

Comment: @SandeshaJ no I can't? As said in question. Countries has multiple Rivers. And Rivers flow through multiple Countries. I don't know how could this be a `@OneToMany`. @TobiasOtto did you look at the previous question I made? Can I Create a StackOverflow room to discuss this topic? If you are willing to? (for an answer I can offer bounty)